# Open and reads a text file, then it copy contents of the file with delimiters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code in excel VBA which open and reads a text file, then it copies contents of the file but it does not paste with delimiters.

I would like to copy the contents of the file that I open and read then paste the contents of the file to another workbook .

Below is the code that I have at the moment

```
Sub ImportTextFile()

Dim SheetName As String
Dim TMPWorkBook As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim TxtFilePath As String
Dim TxtFileName As String

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

path = "C:\Users\"

SheetName = "Test_Result"
TxtFileName = path & "244.txt"

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    TxtFileName _
    , Origin:=437


Set TMPWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
TMPWorkBook.Sheets(1).Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

'ResultWB.Activate
Windows("Sample.xlsb").Activate

'ResultWB.Sheets(SheetName).Select
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
TMPWorkBook.Close savechanges:=False
```

[Image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B88jw.png)

[image]

Comment: What delimiter text file has? comma or something else ? And what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: the sample is below there is no delimeter.              00001105656           240112 000000000DMO SPA                       237679        1  620258901AFACHAT FACTURE       2017030720170719ACHAT FACTURE        0                            00000317441400000014284000000000000000000

Comment: If there is no delimiter how will excel will parse your data ? Leave Excel. How will You parse your data ? It is not possible because excel does not know where to break the  Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening & copy/paste contents I suggest you import the delimited data just as you would via menu option "Data=>From Text".
According to the sample you posted, you might succeed with Space as delimiter.
Here is some code that should get you started:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Dim qt As QueryTable

path = "M:\SSC TQM\Projects\_CC\BPLG\ETAPAI_20170724.txt"
Set wb = Workbooks("TEMPLATE BPLG.xlsb")
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Data")

'Clear existing Query Tables

For Each qt In sh.QueryTables
    qt.Delete
Next qt


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & path, Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    .Name = "Data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
sh.QueryTables(1).Delete
```